# How can I make cloned SurveyInvitation link available for unauthenicated user?

Tags: community, survey, salesforce-survey

When automated SurveyInvitation record is created from Survey Builder Send tab, it is possible to check "Don't require authentication" checkbox to make it possible for anonymous not-authenticated user to submit survey response.
[image]

However, once the SurveyInvitation record is cloned, its link loses the ability to work anonymous not-authenticated users and link requires user to login into customer community.

Can I make the cloned SurveyInvitation record to be just like the origin record so that its link accepts responses from non-authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

The origin record has the specific Share record created.

[image: User Surveys Site Guest User Read Only Survey Sharing Rule]

It is possible to force this Share record creation by running the following code

```
update new SurveyInvitation(
    Id = '0Ki0InvitationId',
    OptionsAllowGuestUserResponse = true
);
```

where you need to substitute 0Ki0InvitationId with the actual Id of Survey Invitation record